# Fetching JSON data from self downloading url

Tags: json, react-native, url, download, fetch

I made some code that fetches data from url's in JSON format. However, I encountered today a url that when you go to it, it automatically starts a download. When I take this download and open it with a browser, I see JSON format data in my browser. So in order to read this data I have to modify my code to locally read that downloaded file. But I don't want to do that because I don't want to store the data on my computer. Is it possible to read this JSON data without actually downloading it ?

edit: @Amadan ... The downloading start if I paste the link in the browser and press enter. Of course if I fetch the link in NodeJS I get an error message. My fetch method works perfect for links to JSON pages that don't trigger a download when I paste the link in the browser.

I fetch with following code:

```
export async function retrieveData(url)
{
  return await fetch(url)
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then((jsonData) => {
   // jsonData is parsed json object received from url
   return jsonData;
})
.catch((error) => {
  throw error;
});}
```

The error message I got says: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to Fetch

Comment: Just `fetch` by itself cannot start a download and save the results to the disk. To answer your question... "some code that you wrote has some error in it" :) You need to actually show us the code before we can say something more precise about what is happening. Please consult [ask] and post a [example].

Comment: A function definition also cannot initiate a download. What is calling this function? How is its return value used? (Also, note that an @ mention in the question body does not ping a user, I randomly checked back.)